# How to validate parameters in string interpolation in case of localization?

Tags: typescript, localization, string-interpolation

In typescript, usually you do string interpolation like this:

```
const name = "Jack"
const message = `Hello ${name}`;
```

This is type checked and if "name" does not exist, you'll get a compilation error. But I have several languages in the application, so my code really looks like this (I am using good old Mustache to format strings, but open to whatever):

```
// strings are coming from external source, like a JSON file:
strings = {
  "message": "Hello {{name}}"
}

const name = "Jack";
const message = Mustache.render(strings.message, { name });
```

So this works, but I would like to have some static checks for the parameters used (so that I get compilation error if in any of the used languages the parameter `name` in the `strings.message` does not exist for example). Is it possible to achieve this somehow? For example, I have seen this library is parsing SQL in a type-safe manner:

https://github.com/codemix/ts-sql

Maybe it could be possible to apply a similar approach to achieve string interpolation for multiple languages? Does anybody have hints? Or maybe there is already a ready-to-use tool, library, or a well-known practice?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://jaysoo.ca/2014/03/20/i18n-with-es2015-template-literals/

Comment: Thank you I'll check it out :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes down to the fact that the string `"Hello {{name}}"` cannot be type-checked as-is. For type checking to work, the `name` would have to be interpreted as a JavaScript identifier, rather than just some substring. So, I don't think using Mustache will work.

You'll need to use a web templating system that's compatible with TypeScript. One option is to use [ReactDOMServer](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html) with Express. You can see an example of it [here](https://flaviocopes.com/react-server-side-rendering/). For your case, the code would look something like:

```
const strings = {
  message: ({ name: string }) => <>Hello {name}</>
};
// Render with:
const App = () => {
  const Component = strings.message;
  return <Component name={name} />;
};
```

Being type safe *will* require you to refactor everything in the `strings` source file, unfortunately (but I'm pretty sure all type-safe solutions will require such a thing).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was thinking maybe in the direction if it is possible to add some custom code (sort of compile-time macros that can execute custom code that can alreayd parse JSON and inject types into code, sort Nemerle-like system). Anyways typescript seems to be moving in this direction (take a look link to the SQL repository - if it could build the type system out of real database that would be super)